# How to sort randomly two or more nodequeues in Views but keeping nodes position?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I've got 3 nodequeues:

Nodequeue A

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

Nodequeue B

- Item 4
- Item 5
- Item 6

Nodequeue C

- Item 7
- Item 8
- Item 9

Does anyone know how to sort these nodequeues in Views (randomly) but keeping the nodequeue position of every node within its nodequeue?

For example:

Nodequeue A, Nodequeue C, Nodequeue B
Nodequeue B, Nodequeue C, Nodequeue A

But items inside every nodequeue stay, based on its original position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution. It's just about grouping nodequeues.

At fields, select "Nodequeue ID" field. Then you can group by this field at Format options.

To mix nodequeues without altering the nodes sorting within the queue just sort by:

- Nodequeue: Position (to keep queue order)
- Global random (only nodequeues blocks will be mixed)

I hope this helps.